# Subset/filter dataframe with comma separated variables in each row

Tags: r, subset

I would like to subset a data.frame that has comma separated variables in each row based on on another data.frame.
df1 (to subset) looks like:
structure(list(Group = c("OG0000000", "OG0000001", "OG0000002",
"OG0000003", "OG0000005", "OG0000005"), C1 = c("K10G4.10, K03D7.7, T06E6.13, F09C3.4, Y47D3A.2, F10A3.17, Y36E3A.1, F44G3.8b, Y67A10A.4, F10A3.2, Y9C9A.12, Y61B8A.4, T09F5.11, C25D7.4a, Y75B8A.21, Y102A5C.19, F47H4.9, C38D9.6, F47H4.4, Y9C9A.8, C02H6.2, C08F11.5a, C38D9.9, F31E9.3, F36G9.14, B0391.9, F14H3.7, M162.11, Y37H2A.12a, Y45F10C.3, Y47H9C.10, Y37H2A.6, Y37H2A.5b, Y37H2A.7, F57G4.8, Y37H2A.18, Y38A10A.4, Y37H2C.3, Y47H9C.12, F56C3.2, C31C9.3, B0391.11a, Y73B3A.22, B0391.5, Y102A5C.1, Y73B3A.15, B0391.6, C38D9.1, C38D9.7, F47H4.8, F44G3.12, F44G3.14, B0511.3, C08E3.9, C08E3.10a, C08E3.6, F45C12.8, ZK1290.9, C36C9.3, T06C12.4, C08E3.7, C08E3.12, C08E3.8, F35E12.3, Y75B12B.1b, F57G4.10, W04E12.1, F28F8.4, F28F8.8a, C17C3.6, C17C3.5, Y102A5C.9, Y102A5C.13, Y113G7B.6, Y113G7B.7, M162.8, Y113G7B.3, Y113G7B.1b, F59A1.7, Y37H2A.4, Y59A8B.11b, Y102A5C.14, Y113G7B.5b, Y113G7B.4, C33E10.2, F14D2.13b, Y57G11C.499",
"Y67A10A.5, H03G16.4, T12B5.7, Y119D3A.1, Y82E9BL.14, Y82E9BL.18, Y119D3B.19, ZC47.7, Y82E9BL.13, T24C2.4, T06E6.15, Y22D7AR.9, Y119D3B.4, Y119D3B.22, Y119D3B.6, T25E12.12, Y22D7AR.2, cTel54X.1, Y82E9BR.12, T20H9.1, Y54F10BM.15, cTel54X.2, Y82E9BL.17, Y119D3A.2, Y82E9BL.7, Y82E9BL.4, F10A3.3, ZC47.4, ZC47.5, Y119D3A.3, Y119D3A.4, ZC47.14, ZC47.3, ZC47.6, Y54F10BM.10, Y82E9BL.11, Y82E9BL.10, Y82E9BL.8, F42G2.8, T13F3.5, T08E11.7, Y82E9BL.15, Y22D7AR.11, T12B5.3, Y54F10BM.5, T12B5.4, C39B5.7, Y54F10BM.20, T20H9.4, Y119D3B.9, Y82E9BL.19, T12B5.5, T12B5.11, F54D10.2, B0294.3, Y119D3B.8, F09C6.2, F09C6.15, F09C6.6, C39B5.9, Y54F10BL.1, T20H9.2, F52D2.1, Y59E1A.1, Y54F10BM.4, C39B5.3, Y54F10BM.11, C17B7.11, T28A11.21, Y119D3B.7, T20H9.3, F54B8.3, C39B5.4, Y54F10BM.7, T12B5.1, F07G6.6, F31F4.15a, ZC47.13a, T12B5.2, F07G6.7, T12B5.6b, T12B5.8, T12B5.10",
"R08A2.4", "F09C3.3, F09C3.5, F49B2.2, Y40B1B.3, Y17G9B.2, F29A7.1a, F29A7.2, F08D12.8, F08D12.6, F08D12.11, F08D12.10, F08D12.9, F53C3.2, F15A4.13, C33E10.8, ZK909.5, T02G5.14, F49B2.1, Y63D3A.9a, C52E2.1, C16C4.6, C52E2.6, C52E2.7, F49B2.7, Y63D3A.3, Y8A9A.5, Y63D3A.2, W03D2.2, F30B5.11, F08D12.15, Y63D3A.10, F15E6.5, M116.1, M116.4, K08E4.8, Y41D4A.3, E04A4.1, Y17G9B.7a, H02I12.2, R08C7.13, R08C7.9, F40F4.1, H24O09.2, C33E10.1, F38H4.2, F07E5.1, C08F8.15, M01D1.12, C41H7.8, C33F10.13, C08F8.5, R07H5.7, C44B9.6, R17.1, T17A3.6, T17A3.4, T17A3.3, T17A3.7",
"E03H12.6", "B0205.2b, F46B3.11, F19B2.8, C32H11.2, C35D6.9a, Y7A9C.7, C09G12.16, W05E7.2, F31E9.5, H12I19.1, H12I19.7, F58E2.9, F56D6.5a, F56D6.4, C39B5.1, F56D6.7, K03D3.4, C04C3.1, Y57G7A.12, Y57G7A.7, C17F4.10, F40D4.9a, Y7A9C.9, C09G12.3, C09G12.2, K03D3.1, C09G12.11, C09G12.10, C18D4.5, K03D3.11, C35D6.13a, C09G12.6, C09G12.15, C35D6.10, K03D3.12, Y102A5C.25, Y68A4A.2, F20E11.1, C55A1.12, H12I19.2, C08F11.9"
), C2 = c("WBGene00270785", "WBGene00088344", "WBGene00039349, WBGene00027461, WBGene00303255, WBGene00027526, WBGene00027525, WBGene00270549, WBGene00027465, WBGene00027468, WBGene00037996, WBGene00041363, WBGene00041365, WBGene00041367, WBGene00037998, WBGene00042987, WBGene00041298, WBGene00041292, WBGene00037999, WBGene00270642, WBGene00034189, WBGene00086898, WBGene00034195, WBGene00270949, WBGene00027324, WBGene00036268, WBGene00027323, WBGene00027443, WBGene00027444, WBGene00027441, CBG22632, WBGene00088690, WBGene00088694, WBGene00088672, WBGene00042834, WBGene00027469, WBGene00027466, WBGene00042618, WBGene00034515, WBGene00041149, WBGene00027326, WBGene00024635, WBGene00042835, WBGene00037338, WBGene00270641, WBGene00271232, WBGene00042721, WBGene00042527, WBGene00042719, WBGene00027540, WBGene00041348, WBGene00271293, WBGene00041345, WBGene00041343, WBGene00042525, WBGene00036831, WBGene00027296, WBGene00027439, WBGene00088721, WBGene00271072, WBGene00271223, WBGene00042617, WBGene00037910, WBGene00042702, WBGene00041148, WBGene00087676",
"WBGene00041416", "CBG11630", "CBG13745")), row.names = c(NA,
-6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7ff0ad8056e0>)

column to subset is C1.

df2 (use to subset):

```
structure(list(V1 = c("K10G4.10", "H03G16.4", "T04B8.3", "F58G1.6", 
"T21G5.5", "E03H12.6")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7ff0ad8056e0>)
```

If I use `df1$C1 %in% df2$V1`, it finds B0024.2 and Y53F4B.33 but not the other two because they are in a row that has other comma separated variables.
I need it to return all the column data for the subsetted rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a regex pattern using `df2$V1` -

```
result <- subset(df1, grepl(sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b', paste0(df2$V1, collapse = '|')), C1))
```

where -

```
sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b', paste0(df2$V1, collapse = '|'))
#[1] "\\b(B0024.2|Y53F4B.33|Y53F4B.32|F58E6.4)\\b"
```

So it will select the row from `df1` if `C1` contains any of these values in it.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure what I'm missing but it I add a variable to df2$V1 that is not in df1$C1, it subsets that row anyway. ie. if I try grepl(sprintf('\\b(%s)\\b', paste0(df2$V1, collapse = '|')), df1$C1) it is TRUE for all rows regards less of whether it is in df1.

Comment: Do you have values repeated in `df2$V1` ? Can you provide a sample dataset using `dput` ? Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Sorry.. should have used dput before.. now edited. I don't think its a result of reproducible values in df2$V1

Comment: @Omics_learner If I run the code on the `dput` shared. `nrow(df1)` is 6 and `nrow(result)` is 3. So it does not select all the rows in `df1`. What is your expected output for this data?

Comment: I had trouble with the rest of the data but its now fixed. You are right, I was wrong. Thanks!